# Problema al generar tablas de multiplicar en PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un programa que desde un formulario genera una tabla de multiplicar en PHP. Tú introduces un número, le das a enviar y genera automáticamente la tabla más abajo en el documento, pero me da un error:

> Notice: Undefined index: numero in C:\xampp\htdocs\practicas\Tema
> 4\ejercicio9.php on line 9
>
> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\practicas\Tema 4\ejercicio9.php on line 9

Pienso que claro que no está definido la variable número hasta que la introduzcamos, por qué no puede continuar el programa? El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    echo "<center><h2>Tabla de multiplicar</h2><br>";
    echo "<b>Introduce el numero que quieras generar su tabla de multiplicar:&nbsp</b>
    <form action='ejercicio9.php' method='get'><input type='text'name='numero' value='' size='30'></form>";
    echo "&nbsp<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>";
    
    do {
         $i=1;
         echo $_GET['numero'] . + "x"  + $i. "=" + $_GET['numero']*$i;
         $i++;
       }
    
       while ($i>=10);
       
     ?>
```

Comment: No son errores, son avisos. Tal vez la primera vez que corres el script no deberías intentar mostrar la tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está solucionado:

Para empezar, `</form>` no incorpora el botón de submit, es un pequeño despiste.
El error era que al ser un for, declarabamos que i volvía a valer uno cada vez que se repetía el loop, siendo así infinito.

Aun así tengo una duda: ¿Porque debemos declarar una variable con el contenido del formulario y no usar `$_GET["VARIABLE"]` en el mismo código? ¿Es mejor usar for o do, que diferencia hay?

Código:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
    echo "<center><h2>Tabla de multiplicar</h2><br>";
    echo "<b>Introduce el numero que quieras generar su tabla de multiplicar:&nbsp</b>
    <form action='ejercicio9.php' method='post'><input type='text' name='numero' value='' size='30'>";
    echo "&nbsp<input type='submit' value='Enviar'></form>";
    $numero_elegido=$_POST['numero'];
    $i=1;
    do {
      echo $numero_elegido." x ".$i." = ".($numero_elegido*$i)."<br />";
      $i++;
    }
    while ($i <= 10);
```

Comment: Los cambios que mencionas mas el hecho de que pasaste de usar get a post